# How to show a running time with seconds in c# web form application on a label?

Tags: c#, time, webforms

How to show a running time with seconds in c# web form application on a label? 
I tried to find it but unfortunately failed. However I found help for the win form application but not for web form. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For the web page you should use javascript/jquery to show or calculate the time: Here is an example:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>A script on this page starts this clock:</p>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 1000);

function myTimer() {
    var d = new Date();
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = d.toLocaleTimeString();
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You shoul use Javascript if you want the timer in the client side (browser).

For example:
http://flipclockjs.com/